# Double Expectation Problem: Finding E[N] of coin flipped until 3 heads appear in a row. N=number of flips

Tags: probability, expected-value

A coin having a probability p of coming up heads is successively flipped until three heads appear in a row. Let N denote the number of flips and find E[N]

This is what I did:

Comment: If the probability of coming up is $p$ for heads, why is the probability of tails $0.5$ rather than $1-p$?

Comment: This is hard to read.  Please insert line breaks between formulas.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If probability of getting a head in a flip is $p$, probability of getting a tail is $(1-p)$, not $0.5$ as in your working.

Expected number of flips to get first head -

$E({\small{H}}) = 1 + (1-p)E({\small{H}}) \implies E({\small{H}}) = \frac{1}{p}$

Expected number of flips to get $2$ heads in a row -

$E({\small{HH}}) = 1 + E({\small{H}}) + (1-p)E({\small{HH}}) \implies E({\small{HH}}) = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2}$

Expected number of flips to get $3$ heads in a row -

$E({\small{HHH}}) = 1 + E({\small{HH}}) + (1-p)E({\small{HHH}})$

$ \implies E({\small{HHH}}) = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^3}$

Answer (score 0):

We can model this problem using an absorbing Markov chain. The state space is $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$, where a state $i\in S$ corresponds to the number of consecutive heads flipped since the last tails (once $3$ consecutive heads are flipped, the process remains in that state). The initial distribution is $\mathbb P(X_0=0)=1$, and the transition probabilities are given by
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
1-p & p & 0 & 0\\
1-p & 0 & p & 0\\
1-p & 0& 0 & p\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
(That is, the $(i,j)$ entry of $P$ denotes $\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$.)

Note that we can write $P$ in block form:
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
T & \mathbf T^0\\
\mathbf 0 & 1,
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $T$ is the substochastic matrix consisting of transitions between transient states and $\mathbf T^0 + T\mathbf 1=\mathbf 1$. Let $p_N(k) := \mathbb P(N=k)$ for nonnegative integers $k$. $N$ has a discrete phase-type distribution, and it is well-known that
$$
p_N(k) = \tau T^{k-1}\mathbf T^0,\quad k=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
There isn't a nice closed form for powers of $T$, but we can still find the expectation. Consider the fundamental matrix
$$
R := \sum_{k=0}^\infty T^k.
$$
Since $T$ is a strictly substochastic matrix (i.e. there is a row which sums to less than one), this series converges, and in fact $R = (\mathbf I - T)^{-1}$, where $\mathbf I$ denotes the identity matrix. The expected number of stepts before being absorbed when starting in transient state $i$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ entry of $R\mathbf 1$. Since
$$
R =  (\mathbf I - T)^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & -p & 0 \\
 p-1 & 1 & -p \\
 p-1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{p^3} & \frac{1}{p^2} & \frac{1}{p} \\
 \frac{1-p^2}{p^3} & \frac{1}{p^2} & \frac{1}{p} \\
 \frac{1-p}{p^3} & \frac{p-p^2}{p^3} & \frac{1}{p} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
it follows that
$$
\mathbb E[N] = p^{-3}(1+p+p^2).
$$